# Crystal report - Show .png image in report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report.

I have saved byte array of .png image in database. I want to show that image in my report. but when i export that report to pdf, it becomes completely black.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: are you able to see in preview?

Comment: can u paste your code here?